# Icecast streaming on a local network

Tags: html, ip-address, audio-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

I'm having trouble accessing my Icecast stream through other computers on the same local network.
I have setup an Icecast server on my laptop: **hostname - myip, port - 8000**.
To stream this I'm using the edcast plugin on Winamp.

To access the stream on the same laptop, I made a basic .html with an audio tag:

```
    <audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" src="http://myip:8000/stream.ogg">
```

The problem I'm facing is when I design the same .html on another pc on the same network, I can't play the stream.
I'm probably messing up the IP addresses.

How do I establish such a setup?
Basically I want this stream that's playing on my laptop to be accessible to other devices on the same local network through a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the TCP port is reachable from other devices on that network. It can e.g. be that a Firewall is in the way and prevents connections from reaching the Icecast server. Local connections are usually handled differently and thus might work, while external connections will be rejected or time out.